# How to change the delay constraints in SDF file for Vivado

Tags: timing, vivado, sdf

Upon running "Implementation" step in Vivado, an SDF file is created along with netlist which is used for Post-Implementation Functional/Timing Simulation. When I change delay constraints in this SDF file and run Timing Simulation, the SDF file is re-written and the edited contraints are removed, replacing the original values.

Any help?

Link from Xilinx post: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Implementation/sdf-file-is-regenerated-after-running-post-implementation-timing/td-p/834176

Comment: SDF file is not supposed to be edited manually. It doesn't constrain anything, it just interchanges the actual timing information between the tools.

Answer (score 0):

I switched back to ISE to test few circuits but yes you’re right it is not supposed to be modified.